# AES - Finite Field Multiplication on 8 Bit Platform

Tags: aes, rijndael

Section 4.1.1 "Finite Field Multiplication"(page 53) of ["**The Design of Rijndael**"](http://jda.noekeon.org/#RijndaelBook), it states

> [image]

#### How the equation 4.1 has been formed and transformed into equation 4.2?

---

In section 2.1.6 "Polynomials and Bytes"(page 15), equation 2.27 and 2.28, highest power of x is 7, whereas in above equations 4.1 and 4.2, it is 8. How?

> [image]

In next line it states

> The multiplication by 02 is denoted xtime(x). xtime can be implemented
>   with a shift operation and a conditional XOR operation.

From Equation 2, it seems all values have been given left circular rotation by 1 bit, but what is Conditional XOR? How this multiplication can be implemented with a shift operation and a conditional XOR operation?

Comment: I bet you have not read the previous chapters of the book, and that the answers are there. -1

Comment: I have added the information from related section 2.1.6, and my query about it in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## I. Polynomial representation

$b_7b_6b_5b_4b_3b_2b_1b_0$ represent the polynomial in $\operatorname{GF}(2)[X]$: $b_7x^7+b_6x^6+b_5x^5+b_4x^4+b_3x^3+b_2x^2+b_1x^1+b_0x^0$ .

$\texttt{02}$ is $\texttt{00000010}$ thus $0x^7+0x^6+0x^5+0x^4+0x^3+0x^2+1x^1+0x^0 = x$.

$b_7x^7+b_6x^6+b_5x^5+b_4x^4+b_3x^3+b_2x^2+b_1x^1+b_0x^0 \cdot x = $
$b_7x^8+b_6x^7+b_5x^6+b_4x^5+b_3x^4+b_2x^3+b_1x^2+b_0x^1+\texttt{0}x^0$
or $b_7\ \ \ b_6b_5b_4b_3b_2b_1b_0\texttt{0}$
that is equivalent to $b_7b_6b_5b_4b_3b_2b_1b_0 \ll 1 = b_7\ \ \ b_6b_5b_4b_3b_2b_1b_0\texttt{0}$

## II. Modulo reduction by $x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$:

This leads to two problems:

- you have a loss of information: you cannot invert the S-box (which would be anoying in the case of AES)
- the upper bit does not fit into the byte

That is why there is the $\bmod m(x)$.

> In the specification of Rijndael, we consider the bytes as polynomials. Byte addition is defined as addition of the corresponding polynomials. In order to define the byte multiplication, we use the following irredutible polynomial as reduction polynomial:
>
> $m(x) = x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$. (2.29, p.16)

Thus we will reduce $b_7x^8+b_6x^7+b_5x^6+b_4x^5+b_3x^4+b_2x^3+b_1x^2+b_0x^1+\texttt{0}x^0 \mod m(x)$.

Remark that:
$x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 \equiv 0 \mod m(x)$
by $a \equiv c \mod m \iff a - b \equiv c - b \mod m$ we have
$x^8  \equiv - x^4 - x^3 - x - 1 \mod m(x)$
because $-1 = 1$ in $\operatorname{GF}(2)$
$x^8  \equiv x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 \mod m(x)$

Thus (going back to our previous equation):
$b_7x^8+b_6x^7+b_5x^6+b_4x^5+b_3x^4+b_2x^3+b_1x^2+b_0x^1+\texttt{0}x^0 \mod m(x) = $
$b_7(x^4 + x^3 + x + 1)+b_6x^7+b_5x^6+b_4x^5+b_3x^4+b_2x^3+b_1x^2+b_0x^1= $
$b_7x^4 + b_7x^3 + b_7x^1 + b_7x^0+b_6x^7+b_5x^6+b_4x^5+b_3x^4+b_2x^3+b_1x^2+b_0x^1= $
grouping by power this leads to:
$b_6x^7+b_5x^6+b_4x^5+b_7x^4 + b_3x^4+b_7x^3 + b_2x^3+b_1x^2+b_7x^1 + b_0x^1+b_7x^0= $
in other terms:
$b_6x^7+b_5x^6+b_4x^5+(b_7 + b_3)x^4+(b_7 + b_2)x^3+b_1x^2+(b_7 + b_0)x^1+b_7x^0$

## III. $\ll$ and $\oplus$

Addition over $\operatorname{GF}(2)$ is equivalent to a XOR ($\oplus$) thus we find the previous formula:
$b_6x^7+b_5x^6+b_4x^5+(b_7 \oplus b_3)x^4+(b_7 \oplus b_2)x^3+b_1x^2+(b_7 \oplus b_0)x^1+b_7x^0$

In the end the multiplication of $b_7b_6b_5b_4b_3b_2b_1b_0$ by $\texttt{02}$ can be seen as:
$(b_7b_6b_5b_4b_3b_2b_1b_0 \ll 1) \oplus \texttt{000}b_7b_7\texttt{0}b_7b_7$
or with a *conditional* XOR:
$(b_7b_6b_5b_4b_3b_2b_1b_0 \ll 1) \oplus b_7\cdot(\texttt{00011011})$

Comment: Thanks a lot :) in last equation . means AND operator and a byte is constructed by b7b7b7b7b7b7b7b7 AND (00011011). or it is multiplication? how do one multiply or AND one bit b7 with 8 bits of 00011011?

Comment: assuming `unsigned bytes` this could be implemented as :  
$(x \ll 1) \oplus  (\sim ((x \gg 7) - 1) \& (\texttt{00011011}))$

Comment: assuming `signed bytes` this could be implemented as :  
$(x \ll 1) \oplus  ((x \gg 7) \& (\texttt{00011011}))$
but this is uses a compiler defined behavior...

Comment: in simple words, there are two scenarios. 1) if MSB of x is 0 then just left rotate x by 1bit. 2) if MSB of x is 1, left rotate x by 1bit and xor with 00011011?

how this equation (x≪1)⊕(∼((x≫7)−1)&(00011011)) is achieving that? why we have negation and - operator?

Comment: **SHIFT** !!!! note rotate.

Comment: `x >> 7` push the $b_7$ to the first bit. The byte value will then be either `0x00` or `0x1`. The `-1` will convert this value to `0x00` if $b_7$ is `1` or `0xFF` if $b_7$ is `0`. The negation will invert all the bits, leading the mask to be `0xFF` if $b_7$ is `1` and `0x00` if $b_7$ is `0`.

Comment: got it :) i was not sure about this. The -1 will convert the value to 0xFF if b7 is 0. I was thinking how -1 will be shown in byte value :) now al cleared :)